# hiphop-php compilation error

Tags: php, fedora, hiphop

I am installing hiphop-php. In the final step(complation) i got an error,

```
-- CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH was missing, proceeding anyway
-- MySQL Include dir: /usr/include  library dir: /usr/lib64/mysql
-- MySQL client libraries: mysqlclient_r
-- Could NOT find LIBMEMCACHED  (missing:  LIBMEMCACHED_LIBRARY LIBMEMCACHED_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at CMake/HPHPFindLibs.cmake:46 (message):
  libmemcache is too old, found and we need 0.39
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/HPHPSetup.cmake:46 (include)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I googled, but not get correct one,   Pls help me

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/issues/526 Perhaps you didn't come across this one.

Comment: Have you installed libmemcached? And is it the newest version?

Comment: yes, i installed libmemcahed through this link

http://php.webtutor.pl/pl/2011/03/31/hiphop-php-instalacja-na-fedora-12/

Answer (score 0):

What instructions are you following and what platform are you on? I just tested ubuntu 12.04 and 13.04 and they worked out of the box.